# Algorithm Perfection Vs Time Analysis : Does Time complexity matters everytime?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have a very basic and general doubt related to algorithm design. I've learnt basic algorithm and now learning randomized algorithm. Everywhere I observed that a professor mostly focuses on designing the algorithm that will ultimately try to reduces the complexity.

The usual way(What I observed) is to learn some basic(or an older) algorithm which behaves badly in terms of complexity and so the objective is to modify that older one with a newer algorithm which should focus on reducing the complexity, without affecting the output.

But in most of algorithm I've studied, especially distributed algorithms (in distributed operating systems) such as algorithms for distributed mutual exclusion, distributed deadlock detection etc., what I observed is that(and mostly I think that) the design of the algorithm should not focus only on complexity enhancement but it should focus on the perfection of the algorithm as well.

Lets take an example of distributed mutual exclusion algorithm. The very basic algorithm is a Lamport's algorithm and the modified version(by enhancing the complexity) of it is the Ricart-Agarwala algorithm. Since in distributed environment the communication is mostly by means of message passing, for distributed mutual exclusion we have three kinds of messages : a) Request critical resource b) Reply the request c) Release critical resource. The basic algorithm uses extra release messages(to inform all sites that the my site has released the critical resource, so you can enter). But in the advanced version what they did is they discarded these release messages by accommodating it in reply messages. And so they came up with some reduced complexity solution.

But when I tried the implementation of these algorithms in java, I observed that even if the complexity of basic algorithm was bit higher but it was more perfect than the advanced one. Because by reducing the number of messages transferred (in advanced solution), local site is no longer aware of the fact that remote site has actually released the resource or not  because on the confirmation of release message only site updates its local data structures such as request queue etc. If we don't send any explicit notification for release, then requests remains pending unnecessarily in request queue of the local site for entire run.

`So my doubt is that if enhancement of complexity is so important, why can't perfection ? I mean if algorithm  is producing perfect results at the cost of bit higher complexity then how does it matters as far as I am getting perfection in output as compared to the enhanced complexity solution which lacks in perfection ?`

Note : By perfection I don't mean correct/incorrect results. Results are always correct. Only the perfection or accuracy of the produced result varies.

Comment: If by "lack of perfection" you mean that you are getting incorrect results, then you should probably assume that you just implemented the algorithm incorrectly.

Comment: The domain of approximation algorithms is exactly about the tradeoff between complexity reduction and result accuracy (if that's indeed what you mean by perfection). If an algorithm is proven to be within a certain distance from the correct answer, it may be good enough for certain practical uses requiring efficient complexity.

Comment: @ mbeckish By lack of perfection I don't mean incorrect results. It simply means that the accuracy of results may get reduced if we only focus on the enhancement of complexity. I am not saying that enhancement always reduces perfection, but in certain algorithm like the one I discussed above, accuracy or perfection really matters a lot than complexity enhancement.

Comment: @ Leeor Actually problem is not of correct answer here. In both cases I discussed above the correct answer is guaranteed. No problem in that, The problem is how accurate the ultimate result is. So to achieve this accuracy how does it matters if site needs to send few extra messages(in above case) because if the ultimate result i will be getting is more perfect and accurate.?

Answer (score 2):

Consider any [NP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Np-complete) problem (e.g. the [travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)).

There are no known non-exponential exact algorithms for these problems (except in special cases), so it would literally take years (or much longer) to find an exact solution for any reasonably-sized version of these problems.

So, instead we use heuristics and approximations (and possibly some randomness) to get a non-exact solution in a reasonable time-frame.

NP-complete problems are just an extreme example - we can also just have a few seconds to get a solution (for whatever reason), but finding an exact solution will take a few minutes. So it all comes down to balancing out how long we want to run the algorithm for and how good we want the results to be (and development time also certainly plays a role).

I hope I understood what you were asking correctly and that this helps.

Comment: Well `development time also certainly plays a role`. I agree and indeed it is a primary goal of algorithm. But in some special cases such as distributed mutual exclusion(as I discussed above), the perfection and accuracy in communication between two or more sites is also important so as to have balanced coordination between them while accessing critical resource. To achieve this perfection if some extra message transfer is required and if it is slightly increasing the complexity(I'm not saying very large increment, it is a very small increment)....

Comment: then how does it matters as long as perfection is there? why can't we accept it?

Comment: @Winn If perfection is there, we'd mainly go for the one that takes the least amount of time (taking dev time into account). Saving a fraction of the time taken for something that happens many times really adds up. I'm not 100% sure I understood the scenario you described, but there can be multiple factors at work here, for example - (1) there's some inefficiency in your code, giving different results than expected, (2) the advanced version is there to deal with some specific cases, which aren't that easy to test for.

Comment: As far as code efficiency is concerned, I've implemented exact algorithm in my program logic, and I've tested it in wireless adhoc distributed network by running it on 5 sites. The code was running fine and it was producing the expected results as mentioned in algorithm. This is what I implemented is the advance solution of above problem. But then I compared its working with the basic approach, I observed the loss of coordination(in advanced solution) between distributed sites just because it has reduced the number of message transfer.

Comment: See this reduction in number of message transfer isn't producing the incorrect results. It is still producing the correct result, No problem in that. But the problem occurs(What I observed after several test iterations) is that at some point of execution(especially for idle sites which are not participating in critical section execution) the lack of these extra messages is making them unaware of the fact that remote site has actually release critical resource or not.

Comment: So in basic approach the transfer of these extra messages were actually helping these idle sites to know what actually is going on in distributed environment so that if they wish to enter critical section in future, they will have perfect knowledge of the network and accordingly will take decision.

Comment: @Winn A problem might be that you only have 5 sites. The advanced version sounds like it's intended for a lot of parties, where it would be inefficient to send messages to everyone. Perfect knowledge is not really viable on a large scale.

Answer (score 2):

Principally a fair complexity comparision is done for two algoritms that produce exactly the same output. E.g sorting.

In your case it is different, you describe algoritms with different behaviour.

To choose the better suited algorithm many factors decide:

- Ease of implementations (in praxis very important)
- A faster algorithm, that lacks some functionallity like in your case must be incredible faster (faktor 10 on expected data volume) to choose it, or easier to implement.
- robustness: well know algo, successfuly used since 10 years, or a new algo from a paper where chance are high that it works only the environment (optimized for the algo) by the scientist.  (I know such a case for a telecom network algo)

Comment: Algorithms what I discussed are almost same. With only modification that number of message transfer is reduced in the advanced solution. Otherwise these both approaches follow same principle. What they mentioned is that they want to reduce complexity(in advanced solution) by reducing number of messages sent, but I then observed while implementing it in java that reduction in messages results in bad coordination between sites and as we know that in distributed mutual exclusion, coordination plays a vital role so as to make an exclusive access of critical resource.

Comment: Many scientist are not interested in the best solution, they have to create a differnet solution where at least one part should be better than the exiting, they do not mention the drawbacks, they come out in practise.

Comment: Does that mean we should add that "BEST" in our implementation of that algorithm ? Won't it affect the expected time complexity by large difference?

Comment: There is no general rule, a fast algorithm well designed can be best and fastest. An algo must be fast enough, should be cheap enough to implement, and if possible not extremely complex such that nobody else would ever understand how the algo works.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "perfection", maybe you should consider "fitness for a particular purpose".

For your example of a distributed mutual exclusion algorithm, consider the "simple" and "improved" algorithms from different viewpoints.  As another answer pointed out, the two algorithms behave differently;  my point is that different people are interested in different aspects of that behavior.

Someone using an algorithm for a particular purpose probably does not care about all aspects of its behavior.  For your example, you are concerned about pending resource locks.  However, if the mutual exclusion algorithm is expected to be running all the time, the user might not care, because the locks will be returned promptly anyway, while using fewer messages than the simple version.  If you want both efficiency and promptness, there is likely some way to accommodate both -- at the cost of greater complexity -- and if you're looking for practical "perfection", this is the logical endpoint.

A computer scientist does not know how his algorithm might be used.  In general, he cannot anticipate all possible variations on a particular technique, and you would not want to read them all if he could!  When publishing an algorithm, clarity of expression is the "perfection" you're pursuing -- the idea should be described as simply as possible.